# splitting string by comma and space in order to store them into 2 different array

Tags: java

I have below string and I wanted to convert into an array.
I want to store all the names into an array and Store the choices that follows the names. For example,

```
String[] name = {"Home", "Sweet", "Smile, ..."}
```

I also want to store their choices as an array:

```
char[] choice = {'A', 'B', 'C', ...}
```

The source `String` is something like this:

```
String ls = "Home A,Sweet B,Smile C,Mind D";
```

FYI : I know how to split by comma, but I do not know how to get the choices. Any help, I will highly appreciate.

Comment: I looks more like you actually want a map, not two separated arrays.

Comment: Chung Lee, both Haseeb Ahmad and WJS provided with good answers. Either one should suffice. WJS used two `String` arrays and Haseeb stored the letters in a `char` array as you requested. BOTH used `"\\s+"` regular expression to match whitespace. This is better than the literal space `" "`.

Comment: @hfontanez , thanks for the recommendation. @ WJS's solution looks good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not use array lists since you said you used arrays.

- first split the arrray on the the comma.
- use that array length to create two other arrays for the names and choices.
- the split on one or more spaces and assign the array element to the arrays.

```
String ls = "Home A,Sweet B,Smile C,Mind D";

String[] s = ls.split(",");
String[] names = new String[s.length];
String[] choices = new String[s.length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    String[] parts = s[i].split("\\s+");
    names[i] = parts[0];
    choices[i] = parts[1];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(choices));
```

prints

```
[Home, Sweet, Smile, Mind]
[A, B, C, D]
```

But if you can use other data structures, an alternative to arrays is a map which lends itself to multiple choice type problems.  Here, the key is the choice and it points to the name (or answer). This just splits the values twice and assigns the second array element to the key and the first to the value.

```
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(ls.split(","))
        .map(str -> str.split("\\s+"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[1], a -> a[0]));

map.forEach((choice, name) -> System.out
        .println(choice + " -> " + name));
```

Prints

```
A -> Home
B -> Sweet
C -> Smile
D -> Mind
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we will split the string using both empty spaces and commas. Then the values at odd indexes will be the choices and the values at even indexes will be names.

**Code:**

```
String ls = "Home A,Sweet B,Smile C,Mind D";
String[] tempArray = ls.split(",|\\s+");
String[] name = new String[tempArray.length/2];
char[] choice = new char[tempArray.length/2];

for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        name[i/2] = tempArray[i];
    }
    else
    {
        choice[i/2] = tempArray[i].charAt(0);
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(choice));
```

For Arrays.toString() to work, you will need to import java.util.Arrays

**Output:**

```
[Home, Sweet, Smile, Mind]

[A, B, C, D]
```

Comment: Did you run the code you posted? My guess is that you didn't. Check it again.

Comment: I corrected your errors. Also, choice array should be an array of `char` and, therefore, should use `tempArray[i].charAt(0)` to convert the single character `String` into a `char`.

Comment: @hfontanez yeah I didn't run it and I noticed there were syntax errors. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\s(.+?),");
      Matcher m = p.matcher("Home A,Sweet B,Smile C,Mind D");
      while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
      }
    } 
}
```

When there are repetitive patterns, regex works well. There are many other patterns that’ll work, but the idea is the same. Once you’ve the tokens, you can put them in arrays or wherever you want.